# Image top left corner

Tags: html, css

I can't get the image on my site to load in the top left corner just below the header.

http://newmanestatewinery.com
Click on our wine and you will see the border around the image

I've tried a few options mainly trying to place the image in my css:

`.wineback {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
}`

However with no luck.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Does the parent have padding?

Comment: Based on Connor's comment, there is padding in the http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css file in the class .ui-content.  If I add the code .ui-content{padding:0px} to my style it changes the 0 padding but, I just want the padding for page3 (our wine) of my website, not the whole thing.  Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `padding:15px` from this selector `.ui-content`

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  Still need some help though. When I add .ui-content{padding:0px} it messes up the padding on the opening page.  Since its in a class, how do I just change the padding for just page3

Comment: You should add a class to the body of each page like `<body class="page-3">` then you would do `.page-3 .ui-content{ padding:0px; }`

Comment: I'm almost there, can you check out: http://newmanestate.x10.mx/  It works now for the picture (thanks a bunch!!!)  I just can't get the default padding back to what it was before, can you provide some recommendations?

Comment: Nothing has changed, you need to add a class to the `<body>` or something